# C++ passing *this in member initialization list

Tags: c++

In C++, I'm trying to have a member variable hold reference to its owner object. This means that I must use *this before constructor body. This compiles in `g++ -std=c++11`. However, is this standard?

```
class Owner
{
    class Data
    {
        friend class Owner; 

        Owner& owner; 
        Data(Owner& owner) : owner(owner) {}
    } data;

public: 
    Owner() : data(*this) {}
};
```

In my specific use, data is a public field, providing access to some functionality of the owner (syntactic sugar as for(element : container))

Comment: Should be, elements are always destroyed in reverse order of creation, so you can never be in a situation where `data` has an invalid reference.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  A bit weird, but not off-limits.

Comment: thanks a lot!
figured it must have been asked already, but could find
tl;dr from the duplicate question: it's legal, but must use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is standard. Your code is correct.